# Get the current fragment in activity outside onBackPressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I searched on how I can get the opened fragment inside activity but found the check must happened in onBackPressed method of that activity

so is it possible to get it in the activity without needing the user click on back pressed?

here is the current solution

```
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();

             Fragment f = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
          if(f instanceof CustomFragmentClass) 
            // do something with f
            ((CustomFragmentClass) f).doSomething();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside your activity class almost in any place.

```
 Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
```

Or in your fragment

```
 Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
```